# C# Sql Server Express not Saved Permanently

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I am using Visual Studio C# 2008 and SQL Server Express. i got a question

i have the following data on my database
[image]

and then, i want to insert a new data

[image]

after that, i have to make sure that the entered data is saved on my database
[image]

it was there, the data was entered succesfully ! but then, when i take a look at my database table
[image]

the entered data was not saved permanently. i need to make the entered data saved permanently. how do i resolve this ?

thanks !

Comment: A side note: using plain text passwords is a bad practice.

Comment: @zerkms yes, thank you for your suggestion. i am concerning about the database now

Comment: what is your connection string?

Comment: @damith Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\proyekTabungan\proyekTabungan\Database.mdf";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True

Comment: Yep, stop doing that. Attach your database to your SQLExpress instance and then your connection string should be `Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=proyekTabungan;...`

Answer (score 4):

You are using the `User Instances = true` + `AttachDbFileName` "feature." When you use this "feature" each application you use will open a *different* copy of the original MDF file. So your C# app opens one copy, you insert a row, but this is never seen in the copy that is open in SSMS / Visual Studio or wherever else you might review the data.

To fix this, ***STOP USING THIS "FEATURE"***.

Create/attach your database to a proper instance of SQL Server, and point to it from your app and SSMS / Visual Studio by referencing the server and the logical database name, not the path to an MDF file.

You'll notice I called this a "feature" - in quotes - multiple times. This is because it is *not* a feature and has caused countless, countless users before you to become absolutely confused about why their inserts and updates "don't work"...

Comment: so i have to use the real `Sql Server Management Studio` ? wow that cost a lot consuming memory.

can it work if i connect them to mysql ?

Comment: @Cignitor No. If you want to do everything in Visual Studio, go nuts; the point is that your app and SSMS, or your app and Visual Studio, or your app and <any other database management tool you use> will have separate copies of the database open if you keep using this AttachDbFileName nonsense. About mysql, shrug, sorry, don't know - I've only ever managed mysql using the web-based admin tools.